# Is there an explanation when spark-csv won't save a DataFrame to file?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-csv

`dataFrame.coalesce(1).write().save("path")` sometimes writes only _SUCCESS and ._SUCCESS.crc files without an expected *.csv.gz even on non-empty input `DataFrame`

file save code:

```java
private static void writeCsvToDirectory(Dataset<Row> dataFrame, Path directory) {
    dataFrame.coalesce(1)
            .write()
            .format("csv")
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("delimiter", "\t")
            .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
            .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
            .save("file:///" + directory);
}
```

file get code:

```java
static Path getTemporaryCsvFile(Path directory) throws IOException {
    String glob = "*.csv.gz";
    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory, glob)) {
        return stream.iterator().next();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(getNoSuchElementExceptionMessage(directory, glob), e);
    }
}
```

file get error example:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: directory /tmp/temp5889805853850415940 does not contain a file with glob *.csv.gz. Directory listing:
    /tmp/temp5889805853850415940/_SUCCESS, 
    /tmp/temp5889805853850415940/._SUCCESS.crc
```

I rely on this expectation, can someone explain me why it work this way?

Comment: Pls feel free to exotic guesses =)

I will be glad to read it too, not just complete solutions and full explonation to my problem

Comment: Do you know if the output file contains records? The movement from ._Success to _Success at least is showing that the write action (logistically-speaking) builds the temp files and moved them to their final resting place.

Comment: Output file should (must by logic) contain at least the header line and some data lines. But he does not exist at all

Comment: During your write statement also include a println("#### Number of output records: " + inputDF.count + " ####"). On the output log run this 'cat output.log | grep ####' . This will be able to tell us if the problem is that your inputDF you are trying to write is empty or not.

Comment: @afeldman inputDf cant be empty by-design. I 
omitted some details for brevity. You can read full class implementation at https://gist.github.com/banyrule/bc8b593de9fcb3fd911742970a890db2

Comment: writeCsvToTemporaryDirectory method prohibits writing empty dataftames via `.format("csv").save`.

Comment: can we do `dataFrame.coalesce(1).limit(1).collect` to eliminate dataframe emptiness as a cause?

Comment: @BanyRule In what `deploy-mode` are you running your Spark app?

Comment: In case you are running this in cluster mode, then the local file output path would mean local path on each and every executor node. Can this be the problem?

Comment: @VihitShah In OP case, it will be local file system of **one executor** that dataframe is being coalesced to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Output file should (must by logic) contain at least the header line and some data lines. But he does not exist at all

This comment was a bit misleading. According to the code on Github, this will happen only if the Dataframe is empty, and won't produce `SUCCESS` files. Considering that those files are present - Dataframe is not empty and the `writeCsvToDirectory` from your code is triggered.

I have a couple of questions:

- Does your Spark job finish without errors?
- Does the timestamp of `SUCCESS` file gets updated?

My two main suspects are:

1. `coalesce(1)` - if you have a lot of data, this might fail
2. `SaveMode.Overwrite` - I have a feeling that those SUCCESS files are in that folder from previous runs

Comment: > if you have a lot of data, this might fail
Result file weighs about 0.5GB . 
>  I have a feeling that those SUCCESS files are in that folder from previous runs
This is obvious, but I have not noticed for so long. Thanks so much for this comment

Comment: Glad to help. 0.5 Gb should work fine with coalesce, unless you have a really small RAM.

Answer (score 3):

It is depend on your storage that you choose to write your csv file.
if you write on hdfs everything's ok. but whenever you decide to write in your local files system you must care that nothing will be written in **driver local files system** and your data will be in worker's files system and you should find them in worker's storage.

**two solution's:**

1. **Run Spark in Local Mode**

set mater local[NUMBER_OF_CORES] that you can submit your job by `--master local[10]` config

2. **Write In Distributed File System**

write your data in distributed file system like s3,hdfs,...

Answer (score 1):

My own solution solved this problem.

I replace `.save("file://"` with `hadoopFileSystem.copyToLocalFile`

The thing is `.save("file://` works expectedly only with `SparkSession.builder().master("local")`, where `hdfs://` is emulated by master's `file://`.

I may be wrong in theory, but it works.

```scala
static Path writeCsvToTemporaryDirectory(Dataset<Row> dataFrame) throws IOException {
    String temporaryDirectoryName = getTemporaryDirectoryName();

    writeCsvToDirectory(dataFrame, temporaryDirectoryName, sparkContext);

    return Paths.get(temporaryDirectoryName);
}

static void writeCsvToDirectory(Dataset<Row> dataFrame, String directory) throws IOException {
    dataFrame.coalesce(1)
        .write()
        .option("header", "true")
        .option("delimiter", "\t")
        .option("codec", "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec")
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .csv(directory);

    FileSystem hadoopFileSystem = FileSystem.get(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration());

    hadoopFileSystem.copyToLocalFile(true,
        new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(directory),
        new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(directory));
}

static Path getTemporaryCsvFile(Path directory) throws IOException {
    String glob = "*.csv.gz";

    try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(directory, glob)) {
        return stream.iterator().next();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(getNoSuchElementExceptionMessage(directory, glob), e);
    }
}

Path temporaryDirectory = writeCsvToTemporaryDirectory(dataFrame);
Path temporaryFile = DataFrameIOUtils.getTemporaryCsvFile(temporaryDirectory);

try {
    return otherStorage.upload(temporaryFile, name, fields).join();
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
} finally {
    removeTemporaryDirectory(temporaryDirectory);
}
```